# Is there any way to use php code with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing an web application, and within it, for security reasons, I would like my users (admin) change system directories right from the admin panel.

For example, he can change the url www.domain.tld/administrator to something like

www.domain.tld/dir1/dir2/dir3/administrator OR
www.domain.tld/dirx1/diry2/dirz3/administratorxyz/pqr

I know that these can be done by .htaccess easily and it can be done by rewriting the .htaccess file by php file handling codes. But I do not want to change the content of the .htaccess file physically, rather, I am looking for something where the user's choice will be stored in database and it will be fetched by a php code and will be used as the .htaccess  code in real time.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Route all requests to a single PHP file with `.htaccess`, and do the inclusions/routing there. It's how most frameworks do it.

Comment: You can redirect all requests to index.php and do everything in the script.